# Matrix printing error when using 2 different arrays created by user

Tags: arrays, c, knapsack-problem

I am trying to print out a 2 x 5 matrix where the first row will have the value of my "profits"(int p[5]) and the second row will have the values for the "weights" (int w[5]). These arrays are both type int and are set using user input.

I want to print out:

p1 p2 p3 p4 p5

w1 w2 w3 w4 w5

but I am getting:

p1, p2, 0, 0, 0

w1, w2, 0, 0, 0

I don't understand why this is happening. How can I solve this?

As mentioned I have

```
int p[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
int w[5] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
// in my code, p and w are set by user 

int i, j;
int m[2][5]; //matrix 

printf("This is the instance you entered: \n\n");
printf("----------------------------------------- \n");

// filling up matrix
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) // rows
{
 for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) // cols
  {

    m[0][i] = p[i]; // profits row

    m[1][i] = w[i]; // weights row
   }
}

// printing m 
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
 for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  {
   printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

/*
this should print:

This is the instance you entered:


-----------------------------------------
1 2 3 4 5

5 4 3 2 1

BUT it prints:
This is the instance you entered:

-----------------------------------------
1 2 0 0 0 

5 4 0 0 0 
*/
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], ideally one which does not require user input.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I think one of the two outer loops is needed.

Comment: @Yunnosch I have provided an example in code

Comment: You should be more specific as to which outer loop to keep and which to delete. Your proposal (even with code) can be misunderstood, though admittedly by ignoring the non-code/comment. @SupportUkraine Also, you could turn the comment into an answer and lavish in the space and formatting that provides.